# How to run netbeans on Android?

Tags: android, netbeans

Please note: **my question is not about developing android application with netbeans.**

I downloaded netbeans for Linux to my tablet, I have JRE working, when I try `./netbeans.sh` I get `error:cannot execute file`

Is it possible to run netbeans on android? how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans uses Java Swing for its UI. If you want to run NetBeans on an Android device, then you must figure out a way to run Swing on Android. Solutions do not abound, but [this fellow](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/java_swing_ui_on_ipad.html) seems to have a suggestion.

Comment: Still searching and testing, found an open source alternative [swingweb](http://swingweb.sourceforge.net/swingweb/)